# spring boot: unable to upload large files (70MB) as multipart request to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I'm unable to upload large files.Please assist.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileToTempLoc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> fileToTempLoc(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseVO>(documentService.fileToTempLoc(request,response), HttpStatus.OK);      
}
```

documentService:

```
    public ResponseVO fileToTempLoc(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){      
    ResponseVO ResponseVO = new ResponseVO();
    final String tempPath = "C:/Users/";
    MultipartHttpServletRequest mRequest;

    try {
        mRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        mRequest.getParameterMap();
        Iterator<String> itr = mRequest.getFileNames();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String uploadedFile = (String) itr.next();
            MultipartFile mFile = mRequest.getFile(uploadedFile);
            String fileName = mFile.getOriginalFilename();              
            Path path = Paths.get(tempPath+"/" + fileName);
            Files.deleteIfExists(path);
            InputStream in = mFile.getInputStream();
            Files.copy(in, path);
            ResponseVO.setStatus(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS);
            ResponseVO.setSuccessMsg("File Uploaded Successfully ");
            ResponseVO.setRedirectUrl(path.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        ResponseVO.setStatus(ResponseStatus.ERROR);
        ResponseVO.setSuccessMsg("Error While Uploading File ");        
        return ResponseVO;
    }       
        return ResponseVO;
}
```

properties:

```
multipart.enabled=true multipart.max-file-size=250MB multipart.max-request-size=250MB
```

I'm able to upload small file(upto 10MB) but not able to upload large files. Please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow - can you tell us more about the error message you are getting when it fails? (i.e. what does the exception say?)

Comment: Zuul proxy returns empty response with code 200 when posting form with big files - without any exception/info

Comment: Yes, that's the response you send in the `catch` part but the exception in there has additional information (in the `e` variable) - you need to look at your log files and debug/inspect the exception (log it, send it to console perhaps) and obtain additional information before we can help you

Comment: it seems service failed at Zuul router itself. not calling the fileToTempLoc methods.

Comment: 2018-01-16 15:20:53.009 DEBUG 15715 ---  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /api/fileToTempLoc reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2018-01-16 15:20:53.010 DEBUG 15715 ---  o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Matching patterns for request [/api/fileToTempLoc] are [/api/**]
2018-01-16 15:20:53.010 DEBUG 15715 ---  o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : URI Template variables for request [/api/fileToTempLoc] are {}

Comment: 2018-01-16 15:20:53.010 DEBUG 15715 ---  o.s.c.n.zuul.web.ZuulHandlerMapping      : Mapping [/api/fileToTempLoc] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController@2a9c17f7] and 1 interceptor
2018-01-16 15:20:53.842 DEBUG 15715 ---  o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2018-01-16 15:20:53.843 DEBUG 15715 ---  w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

Answer (score 0):

Posting in case someone finds this useful in the future. This works with a REST controller as of Spring Boot 2.4.2.

Class annotations:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
```

Method declaration:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/file-upload/{depot}/{fileName}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
        public ResponseEntity<String> fileUpload(
                @PathVariable(name = "depot") String depot,
                @PathVariable(name = "fileName") String fileName,
                InputStream inputStream,
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
```

The above is the Spring Boot configuration for a REST Controller that worked for me for large file upload. The key was adding InputStream inputStream directly.

I also have the following values set in my application.yaml, but as I am not using the Spring multipart processing it's not clear to me if this is in use.

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 500MB
      max-request-size: 500MB
      location: ${java.io.tmpdir}
      file-size-threshold: 0B
```